# My foreach only finds the last element of the array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, nav

This is my first time here.
I have a problem with my foreach loop, it only outputs the "Contact Us" link and none of the others.

I can't see a problem with my syntax:

```
<?php
echo '<nav id="main_nav">';
    $links = array(
        '#' => 'Home',
        '#' => 'About Us',
        '#' => 'Our Services',
        '#' => 'Portfolio',
        '#' => 'Testimonials',
        '#' => 'Gallery',
        '#' => 'Contact Us'
    );
    foreach($links as $href => $label){
        echo '<a href="',$href,'">',$label,'</a>';
    }
    echo '</nav>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is becuase of same index elements in your array........

```
<?php
echo '<nav id="main_nav">';
$links = array(
    '0' => 'Home',
    '1' => 'About Us',
    '2' => 'Our Services',
    '3' => 'Portfolio',
    '4' => 'Testimonials',
    '5' => 'Gallery',
    '6' => 'Contact Us'
);
foreach($links as $href => $label){
    echo '<a href="',$href,'">',$label,'</a>';
}
echo '</nav>';
```

?>

and the answer is `<nav id="main_nav"><a href="0">Home</a><a href="1">About Us</a><a href="2">Our Services</a><a href="3">Portfolio</a><a href="4">Testimonials</a><a href="5">Gallery</a><a href="6">Contact Us</a></nav>`

Comment: You could make this even more simple by omitting the keys in the array definition altogether

Answer (score 3):

That's because you should specify different keys for the elements in your array.

`var_dump($links);` and see your array consists of a single element.

http://ideone.com/epstaT

Answer (score 1):

Beacuse your array key indexes are same. that is why it print only Contact Us

```
print_r( $links );
```

Answer (score 0):

change to `echo '<a href='#'>'.$label.'</a>';` and change the keys and add # by hand, for string concatenation use the dot

Comment: `echo` with commas is perfectly valid. There is no reason to concatenate all the parts to a single string.